# Puzzling crash at application launch

Tags: ios, crash, startup

Many of my users get the crash describes in the below stack trace.
As you can read it seems to happen at the application launch and it does not involved any of our methods if we did not take into account the standard main call at line 28.
I do not know how to fix this bug as I do not manage to reproduce it and the below stack trace is not helpful for me.

The bug appears only on iOS9 (93% iOS9.2, 4% iOS 9.1.0, etc..)
Maybe someone know what to do in this case?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180911bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x181b7b5f4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 372
2  Foundation                     0x181c2430c _NSSetPointValueAndNotify + 284
3  UIKit                          0x18608e798 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] + 656
4  UIKit                          0x185f9b458 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 136
5  CoreFoundation                 0x181188370 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132
6  CoreFoundation                 0x181188268 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 308
7  UIKit                          0x185f89f8c -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 148
8  UIKit                          0x18608e8e0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 128
9  UIKit                          0x1862931f0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 756
10 UIKit                          0x185f7f778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
11 QuartzCore                     0x18398eb2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12 QuartzCore                     0x183989738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13 QuartzCore                     0x1839895f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
14 QuartzCore                     0x183988c94 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
15 QuartzCore                     0x1839889dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
16 QuartzCore                     0x1839820cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
17 CoreFoundation                 0x181248588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18124632c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18124675c __CFRunLoopRun + 928
20 CoreFoundation                 0x181175680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
21 GraphicsServices               0x182684088 GSEventRunModal + 180
22 UIKit                          0x185fecd90 UIApplicationMain + 204
23 once                           0x1000f0f00 main (main.m:14)
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d168b8 (Missing)
```

As an additional information I'm using AFNetworking. Here is the AFNetworking thread stack trace that does not crash:

```
Thread : AFNetworking
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180e194bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180e19338 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181248ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1812467c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181175680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5  Foundation                     0x181b6d21c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6  Foundation                     0x181bc2874 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  once                           0x1001ddf9c +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:169)
8  Foundation                     0x181c53c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180efbb28 _pthread_body + 156
```

Maybe it could help.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does you initial interface include any UITextViews?

Comment: I ask because there is a known bug where you can crash at launch if the initial interface loaded from a nib (storyboard etc.) contains a UITextView.

Comment: thank you for your help. In my case I do not use storyboard or nib files

Comment: Just a wild guess: did you leave some layout debugging code in your app ?  More specifically a KVO on layout constraints.

Comment: Actually, I think I read that stack backwards.  Seems an observer, setup in initialization code, triggers before the UI is ready and attempts to display a view (could it be an error message you want to send to the user under some abnormal condition ?).

Comment: @AlainT. It may be something like that. I'm still searching a way to find the root cause

Comment: I didn't know what AFNetworking was so I looked it up to see if IT could have anything to do with an early UI involvement.  The only thing I found was the activity indicator feature.  That could be an avenue to investigate given that not all users get the error, the triggering condition is likely to be data dependent (or in this case data transfer dependent).   The launch cycle when the app is opened via an URL could also be a suspect given that AFNetworking seems to have a focus on processing remote URLs

Comment: I think I made a bad adoption about when the crash happen. It may happen during the session and when there is interaction with a UITextView. Mays this be helpful?

Comment: @matt as I have no solutions right now, can you, please, point me to a link about the bug you talked about?

Comment: I was referring to the Xcode 7.2 release notes entry that says, "Storyboards and nibs containing UITextViews with 1-11 characters no longer hang when loaded on iOS". That is one of Apple's rare acknowledgements of a serious bug in earlier versions! But you are not using storyboards / nibs, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 0):

I found another entry in SO with a stack that's eerily similar to yours.  There was a resolution involving the removal of a setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO  in a subview.

[issue with reentering of view with [UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] in iOS8 but not iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063871/issue-with-reentering-of-view-with-uiviewgeometry-applyisenginelayoutvalues)

At application startup, this could only be your main view controller or the launchScreen if you have a xib/storyboard for it.